# JAVA | Deserialize JSON Object with inner childs (Objects, arrays, strings)

Tags: java, json, oracle, json-deserialization

I've a JSON structure which is fully dynamic, I don't always know what structure will come from it.

My ideia is to get a `LinkedList<Class>` with PATH and VALUE e.g.

```
Root.Parent1.child1.Property1, Value
Root.Parent1.child1.Property2, Value
Root.Parent1.child2.Property1, Value
Root.Parent2.Array[0], Value
Root.Parent2.Array[1], Value
```

and so on.

I will use this function later in an Oracle DB to parse 1M lines with dynamic json structures. (I've done a pure PL/SQL function but it's extremely slow)

How can I go through a JSON structure as deeper as it goes? Can I use a recursive function?

[Edited]

So far I've done the following tests:

```
String str = "{ \"ProcessData\": {    \"addressID\": \"1-61U0RR\"......"; // big json

Object object = new JSONObject(str);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> mappedObject = mapper.readValue(str, Map.class);
```

But it gives me this (see image) I can't do much with it:

[image]

Comment: Do you use the google.gson library?

Comment: @nonzaprej I've only used jackson and org.json for tests. But I can't do much with this, because it doesn't automatically iterated over the whole structure. And I'm not sure how to apply a recursive function here.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use the [google.gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library and code either a custom [`JsonDeserializer`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) or a custom [`TypeAdapter`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html). You will have to write your specific logic to parse the json.
Here's a question about what's the difference between them: [Gson Type Adapter vs. Custom Deseralizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631004/gson-type-adapter-vs-custom-deseralizer)
And here's a very good tutorial for using `TypeAdapter`s: [GSON TYPEADAPTER EXAMPLE](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy (automatic) solution to deserialize dynamic json objects without extra meta informations.

I would use JsonReader and do it yourself

```
    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(inputStream);
    JsonObject object = reader.readObject();
    object.get(key) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

After a day of work I finaly achieved my goal.

Here's an example of a JSON structure:

```
{
    "Myobj" : 
    {
        "mychild1":"this is my child 1",
        "mychild2":"this is my second child",
        "Myarr":[3,4,5,6,7],
        "mychild3": 
        {
            "myarr2":["A","B","C"],
            "myinnerChild2": 
            {
                "key1":"val1",
                "key2":"val2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here it's the function that  parses the json:

```
 public static Map<String, String> parse(Object json, Map<String, String> out, String arr_index, String root) throws JSONException {
        Class type = json.getClass();
        Iterator<String> keys = null;
        switch (type.getName()) {
            case "org.json.JSONObject":
                keys = ((JSONObject) json).keys();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = keys.next();
                    String val = null;
                    Object value = ((JSONObject) json).get(key);

                    if (value.getClass().getName().equals("org.json.JSONObject") || value.getClass().getName().equals("org.json.JSONArray")) {
                        String obj_key = root + "." + key;
                        parse(value, out, null, obj_key);
                    } else if (value.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.String")) {
                        val = ((JSONObject) json).getString(key);
                    }
                    if (val != null) {
                        key = (arr_index == null) ? key : key + "[" + arr_index + "]";
                        root = root + "." + key;
                        out.put(root, val);
                        root = root.replace("." + key, "");
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "org.json.JSONArray":
                JSONArray jArr = ((JSONArray) json);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
                    Object val = jArr.get(i);
                    parse(val, out, Integer.toString(i), root);
                }
                break;
            default:
                String key = (arr_index == null) ? root : root + "[" + arr_index + "]";
                out.put(key, json.toString());
                break;
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Here it' my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str = "(...)"; //json string
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(str);

        Iterator<String> keys = object.keys();
        Map<String, String> out = new HashMap<String, String>();

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            JSONObject info = object.getJSONObject(key);
            parse(info, out, null, key);
        }

        for (String name : out.keySet()) {

            String key = name.toString().replace(".","/");
            String value = out.get(name).toString();
            System.out.println(key + "->" + value);

        }
```

The output:

[image]