# gson does not accept json data

Tags: java, json, gson

I download the following JSON using the Wikipedia-Api:

```
["aa",
   ["Aarhus","Aalen","Aalborg","Aargau","Aare"],
   ["","","","",""],
   ["https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aarhus",
    "https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aalen",
    "https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aalborg",
    "https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aargau",
    "https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aare"
   ]
]
```

Several online JSON validators accept this format without warning or even errors.

This JSON is rejected by my program:

```
    class OsmWikiResult {
       private String start;
       private String[] file;
       private String[] dummy;
       private String[] link;
    }
... snip ...
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    OsmWikiResult owr = gson.fromJson(inputLine, OsmWikiResult.class);
```

inputLine is containing the whole JSON in one line.

```
java -jar target/OsmWiki-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar xxxx
OsmWiki
getListFromOsmWiki() starting.
Url: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=aa&limit=500&namespace=0&format=json
["aa",["Aarhus","Aalen","Aalborg","Aargau","Aare"],["","","","",""],["https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aarhus","https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aalen","https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aalborg","https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aargau","https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aare"]]
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:774)
    at com.wno.OsmWiki.getListFromOsmWiki(OsmWiki.java:80)
    at com.wno.OsmWiki.main(OsmWiki.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
    ... 6 more
```

walter

Comment: Your object would map to a JSON **object** with the keys `start`, `file`, `dummy` and `link`. You're giving it an **array** with one string and three arrays inside.

Comment: Any hint to do it better?

Comment: While your JSON is valid, it simply does not match the Java data structure. To see why, you can try the opposite conversion. Let the class serialize into a JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're attempting to parse an *array* into an *object* with keys `start`, `file`, `dummy` and `link`. You need to parse the root array into a `JsonArray`, then get the individual elements from that.

In its simplest form, something like this will work:

```
JsonArray root = parser.parse(inputLine).getAsJsonArray();

String searchedTerm = root.get(0).getAsString();
String[] resultTitles = gson.fromJson(root.get(1), String[].class);
String[] dummy = gson.fromJson(root.get(2), String[].class);
String[] links = gson.fromJson(root.get(3), String[].class);
```

I would suggest creating a custom `JsonDeserializer` or `TypeAdapter` to be able to just `gson.fromJson()` the whole shebang. Since your JSON doesn't have very deep nesting, I think you'll be able to get way with just implementing  a `JsonDeserializer`. Just be aware that if you start running into performance issues, you might want to implement a `TypeAdapter`. Read more about their differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631004/gson-type-adapter-vs-custom-deseralizer).

Try this one out:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputLine = "[\"aa\",[\"Aarhus\",\"Aalen\",\"Aalborg\",\"Aargau\",\"Aare\"],[\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\"],[\"https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aarhus\",\"https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aalen\",\"https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aalborg\",\"https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aargau\",\"https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Aare\"]]";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(OsmWikiResult.class, new WikiSearchResultDeserializer())
                .create();

        OsmWikiResult result = gson.fromJson(inputLine, OsmWikiResult.class);
        System.out.println("result.getSearchTerm() = " + result.getSearchTerm());
        System.out.println("result.getResults() = " + String.join(", ", result.getResults()));
        System.out.println("result.getLinks() = " + String.join(", ", result.getLinks()));
    }
}

class WikiSearchResultDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<OsmWikiResult> {

    @Override
    public OsmWikiResult deserialize(
            JsonElement json,
            Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context
    ) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray root = json.getAsJsonArray();
        String searchTerm = root.get(0).getAsString();
        String[] results = context.deserialize(root.get(1), String[].class);
        String[] dummy = context.deserialize(root.get(2), String[].class);
        String[] links = context.deserialize(root.get(3), String[].class);
        return new OsmWikiResult(searchTerm, results, dummy, links);
    }
}


class OsmWikiResult {
    private String searchTerm;
    private String[] results;
    private String[] dummy;

    private String[] links;

    public OsmWikiResult(String searchTerm, String[] results, String[] dummy, String[] links) {
        this.searchTerm = searchTerm;
        this.results = results;
        this.dummy = dummy;
        this.links = links;
    }

    public String getSearchTerm() { return searchTerm; }
    public String[] getResults() { return results; }
    public String[] getDummy() { return dummy; }
    public String[] getLinks() { return links; }
}
```

Notice how you need to register the deserializer with Gson so that it knows what to do when parsing an `OsmWikiResult`. The deserializer just plucks out the array's elements in correct order from the API result's array.

Comment: great, will try.

btw: would like to close this problem (found another solution using postgresql/json), but i'm not allowed.